# チェックボックス付きのコンボボックス（リストボックス）について

Tags: python, python3, tkinter, tk

こういう感じのものを私の環境で実現する方法はありますか？（tkinter 以外ならありますか？）

[【.NET】コンボボックスで複数選択する方法](https://qiita.com/yaju/items/369cb5be0c0298859b3e)

●私の環境について
・Python 3.9.7
・tkinter '8.6.12'
・PyCharm 2021.3.3 (Community Edition)

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781047/tkinter-drop-down-list-of-check-boxes-combo-boxes 本家サイトの方におなじ質問がありましたので読んでみてください

Comment: ありがとうございます。勉強してみます。

Comment: 質問のタイトルは「～について」で切るよりも、「～したい、～できない」の様に言い切った方が伝わりやすいと思います。今回の場合なら「Tkinter でリストボックスを作成したい」のような感じで。

Comment: @gesto さんの紹介記事で更に紹介されている [hatfullr/ChecklistCombobox](https://github.com/hatfullr/ChecklistCombobox) が丁度該当していそうですね。そのgithubページに記載されているテストプログラム`checklistcombobox.py`を実行すると質問の紹介先に書いてある動作をしているように見えます。gestoさんがそれを回答とするか、BrainOverflowさんの検証結果がOKならばそれをもって自己回答されるのが情報共有となって良いと思われます。

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/hatfullr/ChecklistCombobox
ですが、下記のようにやれば最低限のことはできそうです。

```
１．checklistcombobox.pyを、プロジェクト内のimport可能な場所に置く。

２．設定
#適宜fromなどを使って、import
import checklistcombobox as CombChk

#チェックボックスの名前（コンボボックスに表示されるチェックボックスごとの名前）
lst_ChkboxLabel = ['ChkBox1', 'ChkBox2', 'ChkBox3', 'ChkBox4', 'ChkBox5']


３．クラス定義
class C_CHEFK_LIST_COMBO_BOC():

    #初期設定
    def __init__(self):

        #value= で、上記リストを設定すると、その要素数に応じてチェックボックスが作られる。
        #配置や大きさは標準装備のウィジェットと同様に設定。
        self.CmbChk = CombChk.ChecklistCombobox(root, values=self.lst_ChkboxLabel,width=20, height=18)
        self.CmbChk.configure(checkbutton_height=1) #行の高さ
        self.CmbChk.pack(side=tk.TOP)

    #値の取得
    def Get_CmbChk_Status(self):
    
        chk_status = self.CmbChk.get()  #返却値でチェックされた部分のリストが返される。


chk_statusについて。
    例えば、lst_ChkboxLabelで、ChkBox1', 'ChkBox3', 'ChkBox5にチェックがついていた場合
    chk_status = ['ChkBox1', 'ChkBox3', 'ChkBox5']
になる。
```